# how to implement roundup function in java

Tags: java, math

How to achieve functionality similar to excel's Roundup() in java?

for example - how to round 0.3102 to 0.4 in java ?

Comment: You can simply use `r = Math.ceil(r * 10d) / 10d`. I think thats faster then instancing BigDecimal.

Comment: Or even `Math.ceil(r*10)/10d` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigDecimal can help in achieving this.

for example-

```
 // new BigDecimal(<your-number>).setScale(<scale-value>, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP)) 
 result =  new BigDecimal(0.3105).setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP));

 // result = 0.4
```

Answer (score 5):

```
double r =0.3102;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(r);
bd = bd.setScale(1,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
r = bd.doubleValue();
System.out.println(r);
```